# Cython: Tutorial cannot find external symbols that are never referenced

Tags: python, c, cython

So I am completely new to programming in C on a computer (I once compiled code in college, but that is it) so when I was trying to learn Cython I was hopeful I wouldn't have to REALLY learn any C.  Maybe I was too hopeful?

Anyway, i am doing the tutorial [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) and encountering issues with the generated C code.  Namely, it is giving the following errors:

```
___pyx_pf_5queue_5Queue___dealloc__
queue.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _queue_new referenced in function ___pyx_pf_5queue_5Queue___cinit__
\\Vs1\fs2\Operations\Software\VixarFiles_Dev\Playground\cython\tutorial and calgorithms src\queue.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I don't know where it is getting an "_" in front of those names, it must be writing them itself somewhere when it creates teh C code (it's nowhere in my code).  Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Possible causes of the problem:
-  Ok, I didn't follow the tutorial PERFECTLY.  I haven't built or installed the library, I simply threw the source code into the same folder as my python files (and named them differently to ensure it didn't overwrite the *.c files).  From what I did in C++ class, this should be fine.  Is there any reason it might not be?  If so, I have no clue how to build a C file normally.

I would like to know if anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong or of a good steps I might take to find out how to solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you actually did. File listings, error messages, debug output, the whole bit.

Comment: To effectively use Cython, you will need to know some C, at least at present. Otherwise, just stick to Python.

Comment: I have the same problem - I suspect it relates to C name mangling on x86 architectures. See also http://forum.pellesc.de/index.php?topic=4103.0 and https://github.com/SciTools/conda-recipes-scitools/issues/29. I don't yet have a solution to the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is not with knowing C as a language, but is related to getting the proper libraries in your path.  When queue.obj is throwing an "unresolved external reference" error, it usually means that C code (that cython generates) calls some function from a library, but your build system can't find the library.  Sorry, but I am also new to cython, so I can't rattle off the expected path for the _queue_new function.